# Unity3d: Camera Effects look different in different screen sizes

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, camera, post-processing, scalable

I have applied some post processing effects to my camera. They looked fine in the free aspect minimized game view but when I maximize it or change the aspect ratio the effects look different. And also how can I make my UI elements change as the screen size changes.

Images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in post processing stack and is still not fixed by them. But I found a fix [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/issues/29).

Fix:

open the DepthOfFieldComponent.cs, remove const from before k_FilmHeight, then have it update somewhere such as in Prepare, above CalculateFocalLength, add something like: k_FilmHeight = 0.024f * (Screen.height / 720.0f);

720 can be changed to whatever number you want to use as your default screen height.

Comment: This is interesting. Haven't heard about this before.

Comment: Yes it is and thats why it is important to check game on different resolutions.